# How to Add logo to the Email address verification sent from Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

i am using Firebase Email Verification, but After sending the verification link to user, Firebase is not showing the company Logo as the sender.

base on this image i want to able to show the company logo when ever Email verification is been sent

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Log in with your company email address, go in manage account and change your profile photo for the account and save the settings, this way your display photo will be changed everywhere you use this account

Comment: i dont understand... please put more light

Comment: log in with your company email address, go in manage account and change your profile photo for the account and save the settings, this way your display photo will be changed everywhere you use this account.

Comment: @D0ll4R: That’s useful. Please [edit] your answer to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default Firebase domain (e.g., myappname.firebaseapp.com) for your custom domain?

If you're using your own domain, this setting mostly lies on your email address setup.

Comment: i am using a custom domain..